# what does bool? isActive = false mean in c#?

Tags: c#, boolean

As the question depicts, what does the following code mean?

```
public void blabla (bool? isActive = false) {

}
```

Comment: I didn't know C# supported default parameters

Comment: of course it does - C# tries to support EVERYTHING - even nullables which I totally think are pointless

Comment: @Kshitij as of C# 4, it has named and optional parameter support.

Comment: @Quantic: That is factually incorrect. C# does *not* try to support everything, or even *most* things. They've been slowly adding support for more and more constructs at the requests of their user base. You may not see the point in nullables, but they're quite useful in certain applications. But there are still many concepts well-supported by other popular programming languages that C# does not support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it is a void method (returns nothing) taking an optional parameter (`isActive = false`) of a nullable boolean (`bool?`), where the default value is false.

It is a public method, meaning that code that has access to the class / struct that contains this method can see the method.  The `public` is called an access modifier.

Access modifiers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(v=VS.100).aspx

Optional parameters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Nullable types:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=VS.100).aspx

As for it's *significance*, that depends if it's responsible for keeping planes in the air or not :-P

Comment: lol I edited my question, I meant what does it mean :) I was just confused from the italian word significato :)

Comment: @Shaokan I sort of guessed, but I thought I'd add it for comedy purposes :-)

Answer (score 6):

`bool?` indicates that it's a nullable type, supporting `true`, `false` or `null`.  `= false` indicates that if a value isn't supplied, it is `false` which is the default value.

Answer (score 2):

its an optional parameter of nullable boolean with a default value of false

Answer (score 1):

It makes bool a nullable type:

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It means it makes a new method, and a parameter with a DEFAULT value - that means you can call it by two ways:
`blabla(true);` or `blabla(false)` or `blabla(null)`
or:
`blabla()` and it'll give the default value of FALSE.